# Can i override phone's culture settings in WP7 application

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization, globalization, marketplace

I looked through MSDN and couldn't find a clear cut answer to this one. So, if i'm building a localized WP7-application, should i conform to phone's language/culture settings or can i roll my own language/culture-switching mechanism inside the app?

Here's the relevant section from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637522(v=vs.92).aspx

This is stated in "Testing Your Application":

> When changing a display language, verify that the language of your
>   application UI automatically updates to that language.

Should this be taken as a "soft" guideline or a precondition for Marketplace acceptance?

ps. I know that this question is pretty academic in nature, because i cannot think of any scenario where standard localization mechanism wouldn't be enough.

Edit: 
To clarify my point: If i build a localized/globalized app, am i required to or should i use the phone's settings or can i implement my own culture switching?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to perform this sort of test on a real device, by navigating to `settings > region + language`. In this page you can change language and other locale information such as date format.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is not what i meant. My point is that if i would roll my own culture-switcher overriding phone's settings, would that be against guidelines for WP7 apps?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I guess a developer may implement "own" language switching mechanism inside the app. One example is: I have English choosen as a device language but Czech as region I live. I don't want to see whole OS in Czech but I would like to see one specific application (which supports Czech) in Czech language. It means, without switching OS to Czech this cannot be provided. For this scenario, I think, is the best to have a possibility to choose the language in the app as well - so I can stay in English OS language and I can switch this app to Czech.